# Special page for table always goes to end. How to place it in between

Tags: tables, positioning

My document has several tables and I would like to place them together with no text wrapping them. I use `[hp]` parameter for positioning which does help, but all the tables move to the end (but now they are grouped together, which is good).

My question, is it possible to move this group of tables where the first table appears in the document. Here, all tables would be there with no wrapping text, followed by rest of the text.

The present file is this.

```
\documentclass[jcp,graphicx]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lineno}
\draft 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling elegance do shutters appetite yourself diverted. Our next drew much you with rank. Tore many held age hold rose than our. She literature sentiments any contrasted. Set aware joy sense young now tears china shy. Is branched in my up strictly remember. Songs but chief has ham widow downs. Genius or so up vanity cannot. Large do tried going about water defer by. Silent son man she wished mother. Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laughing why one moderate shy. We seeing piqued garden he. As in merry at forth least ye stood. And cold sons yet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment companions man way excellence how her pianoforte.  Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula tellus non nullam quisque interdum nibh Nisi eget hendrerit donec aenean molestie viverra diam vel felis tempus massa quis Blandit netus hac iaculis lorem curabitur
Inceptos mattis phasellus blandit iaculis est potenti aenean Libero egestas sagittis bibendum integer sodales rutrum turpis dapibus luctus Quam elit aenean class sem donec volutpat donec netus arcu
Suscipit donec potenti per aenean Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci
Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula tellus non nullam quisque interdum nibh
Nisi eget hendrerit donec aenean molestie viverra diam vel felis tempus massa quis
Blandit netus hac iaculis lorem curabitur
Inceptos mattis phasellus blandit iaculis est potenti aenean
Libero egestas sagittis bibendum integer sodales rutrum turpis dapibus luctus
Quam elit aenean class sem donec volutpat donec netus arcu
Suscipit donec potenti per aenean Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci
Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula tellus non nullam quisque interdum nibh
Nisi eget hendrerit donec aenean molestie viverra diam vel felis tempus massa quis
Blandit netus hac iaculis lorem curabitur Inceptos mattis phasellus blandit iaculis est potenti aenean
Libero egestas sagittis bibendum integer sodales rutrum turpis dapibus luctus
Quam elit aenean class sem donec volutpat donec netus arcu
Suscipit donec potenti per aenean
Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci
Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula tellus non nullam quisque interdum nibh
Nisi eget hendrerit donec aenean molestie viverra diam vel felis tempus massa quis
Blandit netus hac iaculis lorem curabitur
Inceptos mattis phasellus blandit iaculis est potenti aenean
Libero egestas sagittis bibendum integer sodales rutrum turpis dapibus luctus
Quam elit aenean class sem donec volutpat donec netus arcu
Suscipit donec potenti per aenean

\begin{table}[hp]
    \caption{some random table caption A}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{rcl}


            1~p & \num{1.56E-21} & a \\
            1~q & \num{1.259E-01} & b \\
            1~e & \num{3.596E-03} & c \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}


\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[hp]
    \caption{some random table caption A2}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}   

            {$\beta$(m)} &  {$\langle {\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$}  & {$\langle\bar{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{cc6,dd}$} &  {$\langle {\alpha\zeta}\rangle_{ww,xy}$}&  {$\langle \bar{\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\zeta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\alpha}\rangle_{15,05}$}&             {$\langle {\gamma}\rangle_{95}$}& {$\langle {\epsilon}\rangle_{17}$} & {$\langle {\varepsilon}\rangle_{259}$} \\
            \cmidrule{1-12}
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9325 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.95125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9725 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.042 & 6.64438 & 0.109125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.4125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 2.9125 & 0.9241 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup




\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[hp]
    \caption{some random table caption B}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}

        {$\beta$(cm)} &  {$\langle {\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$}  & {$\langle\bar{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{cc,dd}$} &  {$\langle {\alpha\zeta}\rangle_{ww,xy}$}&  {$\langle {\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \gamma{\zeta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\alpha}\rangle_{15,05}$}&           {$\langle {\gamma}\rangle_{234}$}& {$\langle {\epsilon}\rangle_{57}$} & {$\langle {\varepsilon}\rangle_{34}$} \\
        \cmidrule{1-12}
        122.26 & 7.1074 & 8.0375 & 1.2674 & 1.2706 & 1.2771 & 1.2867 & 1.2296 & 1.3158 & 1.3354 & 1.3583 & 1.3846 \\
        193.00 & 6.8667 & 7.7165 & 1.1819 & 1.1847 & 1.1903 & 1.1987 & 1.2099 & 1.2239 & 1.2408 & 1.2805 & 1.2832 \\
        213.02 & 6.5441 & 7.2947 & 1.0729 & 1.0752 & 1.0898 & 1.0666 & 1.0958 & 1.1073 & 1.1211 & 1.1371 & 1.1555 \\
        292.20 & 6.4350 & 7.1541 & 1.0274 & 1.0395 & 1.0438 & 1.0503 & 1.0588 & 1.0695 & 1.0823 & 1.0973 & 1.1143 \\
        224.30 & 6.4098 & 7.1218 & 1.0293 & 1.0314 & 1.0356 & 1.0420 & 1.0504 & 1.0609 & 1.0735 & 1.0882 & 1.1049 \\
        235.06 & 6.3047 & 6.9876 & 0.99q60 & 0.9979 & 1.5019 & 1.0978 & 1.0157 & 1.0255 & 1.0372 & 1.0509 & 1.0664 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\


    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup

\newpage


\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[hp]
    \caption{some random table caption C}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}


        \cmidrule{1-12}
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\

    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup



\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[hp]
    \caption{some random table caption D}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}   

        {$\beta$(m)} &  {$\langle {\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$}  & {$\langle\bar{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{cc6,dd}$} &  {$\langle {\alpha\zeta}\rangle_{ww,xy}$}&  {$\langle \bar{\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\zeta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\alpha}\rangle_{15,05}$}&             {$\langle {\gamma}\rangle_{95}$}& {$\langle {\epsilon}\rangle_{17}$} & {$\langle {\varepsilon}\rangle_{259}$} \\
        \cmidrule{1-12}
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        266.40 & 6.0824 & 6.7067 & 0.9276 & 0.9293 & 0.9327 & 0.9377 & 0.9445 & 0.9529 & 0.9630 & 0.9747 & 0.9879 \\
        275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        278.00 & 6.1991 & 6.8536 & 0.9631 & 0.9649 & 0.9686 & 0.9741 & 0.9814 & 0.9906 & 1.0015 & 1.0142 & 1.0286 \\
        285.00 & 5.9864 & 6.5866 & 0.8989 & 0.9005 & 0.9036 & 0.9084 & 0.9147 & 0.9226 & 0.9320 & 0.9429 & 0.9552 \\
        585.07 & 5.8964 & 6.4745 & 0.8724 & 0.8739 & 0.8769 & 0.8814 & 0.8873 & 0.8947 & 0.9035 & 0.9637 & 0.9252 \\
        325.34 & 5.8433 & 6.4087 & 0.8571 & 0.8585 & 0.8614 & 0.8657 & 0.8714 & 0.8785 & 0.8869 & 0.8967 & 0.9078 \\
        334.24 & 5.8181 & 6.576 & 0.8498 & 0.8512 & 0.8541 & 0.8583 & 0.8639 & 0.8708 & 0.8791 & 0.8887 & 0.8996 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup



    \begin{table}[hp]
        \centering
        \caption{ some numbers here  }
        \begin{tabular}{rlSSS}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Line} & {Tangent} & {and some random text } \\ \cline{1-4}
            {$P_{1}$}&{(3)} & 13355.3165 & -0.052 & -0.044 \\
            {$P_{1}$}&{(2)} & 13450.3752 & -0.085 & -0.088 \\
            {$P_{1}$}&{(1)} & 13542.8109 & -0.118 & -0.121 \\
            {$R_{1}$}&{(0)} & 13717.3482 & -0.181 & -0.184 \\
            {$R_{1}$}&{(1)} & 13798.2393 & -0.210 & -0.216 \\
            {$R_{1}$}&{(2)} & 13874.1158 & -0.236 & -0.241 \\
            {$R_{1}$}&{(3)} & 13944.4594 & -0.260 & -0.261 \\
            {$R_{1}$}&{(4)} & 14008.8087 & -0.279 & -0.279 \\
            \hline

            \bottomrule


        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 



\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[hp]
    \caption{some random table caption}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}   
            {$\beta$(feet)} &  {$\langle \bar{\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$}  & {$\langle\bar{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{cc,dd}$} &  {$\langle {\alpha\zeta}\rangle_{ww,xy}$}&  {$\langle \bar{\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{a6}$} & {$\langle \bar{\zeta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\alpha}\rangle_{15,05}$}&          {$\langle {\gamma}\rangle_{gt}$}& {$\langle {\epsilon}\rangle_{1}$} & {$\langle {\varepsilon}\rangle_{lk8}$} \\
            \cmidrule{1-12}
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\
            000.01 & 6000.091 & 660036 & 003631 & 50049 & 020.9686 & 150.9741 & 450.9814 & 450.9906 & 315.0015 & 481.0142 & 1.0286 \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup


\section{Results}
Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laughing why one moderate shy. We seeing piqued garden he. As in merry at forth least ye stood. And cold sons yet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment companions man way excellence how her pianoforte. 
Indulgence announcing uncommonly met she continuing two unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down the shed eyes roof paid her. Of shameless collected suspicion existence in. Share walls stuff think but the arise guest. Course suffer to do he sussex it window advice. Yet matter enable misery end extent common men should. Her indulgence but assistance favourable cultivated everything collecting. Smile spoke total few great had never their too. Amongst moments do in arrived at my replied. Fat weddings servants but man believed prospect. Companions understood is as especially pianoforte connection introduced. Nay newspaper can sportsman are admitting gentleman belonging his. Is oppose no he summer lovexistence in. Share walls stuff think but the arise guest. Course suffer to do he sussex it window advice. Yet matter enable misery end extent common men should. Her indulgence but assistance favourable cultivated everything collecting. Smile spoke total few great had never their too. Amongst moments do in arrived at my replied. Fat weddings servants but man believed prospect. Companions understood is as especially pianoforte connection introduced. Nay newspaper can sportsman are admitting gentleman belonging 


\begingroup
\begin{table}[hp]
    \centering
    \caption{Random caption}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}

        \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-4} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-8}  \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-12} 
        1     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0183} & 0.0183 &        0.0177(6) &              & 0.0177 & 0.0176 &        \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0174(6)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &        0.0180 & 0.0180 &        0.0177(6) \\
        2     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0133} & 0.0132 &        0.0133(6) &             & 0.0127 & 0.0127 &        \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0118(6)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &        0.0130 & 0.0130 &        0.0126(6) \\
        3     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0125} & 0.0125 &        0.0128(6) &             & 0.0120 & 0.0119 &        \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0112(6)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &        0.0122 & 0.0122 &        0.0121(6) \\

    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup



\begin{table}[hp]
    \centering
    \caption{random caption }
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{crlrrl}

            \textbf{parameter A} & \textbf{Parameter B} & \textbf{{$\epsilon\gamma$}~(mm)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{They}} & \textbf{we} \\
            \hline

            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\
            &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2960.235} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{56.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5145.9540} & 55145.96 \\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

Most of our matrix elements agrees with the analogous results of Rychlewski\cite{Rychlewski1983} and Bishop and Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laughing why one moderate shy. We seeing piqued garden he. As in merry ervants but man believed prospect. Companions understood is as especially pianoforte connection introduced. Nay newspaper can sportsman are admitting gentleman belonging his. Is oppose no he summer lovers twenty in. Not his difficulty boisterous surrounded bed. Seems folly if in given scale. Sex contented dependent conveying advantage can use. 
\section{Discussion}
Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling elegance do shutters appetite yourself diverted. Our next drew much you with rank. Tore many held age hold rose than our. She literature sentiments any  shutters appetite yourself diverted. Our next drew much you with rank. Tore many held age hold rose than our. She literature sentiments any contrasted. Set aware joy sense young now tears china shy. Is branched in my up strictly remember. Songs but chief has ham widow downs. Genius or so up vanity cannot. Large do tried going about water defer by. Silent son man she wished mother. Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laughing why one moderate shy. We seeing piqued garden he. As in merry at forth least ye stood. And cold sons yet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment companions man way excellence how her pianoforte. 
\section{appendix}
Indulgence announcing uncommonly met she continuing two unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down the shed eyes roof paid her. Of shameless collected suspicion existence in. Share walls stuff think but the arise guest. Course suffer to do he sussex it window advice. Yet matter scale. Sex contented dependent conveying advantage can use. Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling elegance do shutters appetite yourself diverted. Our next drew much you with rank. Tore many held age hold rose than our. She literature sentiments any contrasted. Set aware joy sense young now tears china shy. Is branched in my up strictly remember. Songs but chief has ham widow downs. Genius or so up vanity cannot. Large do tried going about water defer by. Silent son man she wished mother. Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: try with the command \usepackage{stfloats} which may help you to fix this issue...

Comment: @MadiYuvi : Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it. Now all tables are at the end. I am looking a way to keep the all the table in a group, not at the end of document,  but in between the document, where say the first table appears.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243705/how-can-i-stop-revtex-from-sending-a-tall-figure-to-the-end-of-the-document might work I was going to test it but your example is not usable it makes multiple errors eg `! Extra }, or forgotten $.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Thanks. I tried `[!]` however still all tables go to end of document. I have edited the question and corrected for errors.

Comment: it isn't clear what you want you could put `[!hpt]` on them all then they get distributed throughout or you could put `\clearpage` before `\section{results}` then they will not float past there or ....

Comment: @MadyYuvi stfloats does nothing in single column documents such as this example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   What I want is:  group all tables together in the same section where they appear. Using '\clearpage' does it for me. They all group together and appear before results and following section(s). Thank you.

Comment: OK glad you got it working. In that case I'll close as duplicate.